# How to pass JSON as parameter to Post method in controller .net api

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, post

first I want to say that I'm newbie in asp.net and I'm trying to learn atleast the basic stuff for now so don't be harsh on me :)
I have a post method in my controller which has to recieve a json from post request body and after that add the information to the database. So here is the method:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<DeviceData> InsertData(DeviceData deviceData)
    {
        var device = deviceContext.Devices.Find(deviceData.Id);

        if (device == null)
        {
            return BadRequest(Messages.DeviceNotExist);
        }

        deviceContext.DeviceData.Add(new DeviceData
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
            Latitude = deviceData.Latitude,
            Longitude = deviceData.Longitude,
            Altitude = deviceData.Altitude,
            Speed = deviceData.Speed,
            DeviceId = deviceData.DeviceId
        });
        deviceContext.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(deviceContext.DeviceData.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Last());
    }
```

My best guess is that my parameter is not correct since I'm trying to pass json and the paramater in the method is DeviceData type.
So my question is what should I change and add to get the json body of the request and use the data to perform insert to the database and after that return a response-the json object?
I'm using Postman for requests if it matters.

Comment: What is the error? And post your json that you are using for postman.

Comment: you are checking if device if exist and if exist trying to add.  What are doing? are adding a new device or updatating?

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Serge I have two models: device and device data. Device data has a relation to device with its Id because if I have for instance 5 devices I want to know which have posted data in Device data table in the database. So yes first I check if device exists and if it does then I'm adding new data record in the data table related to that device. I'm sending post request to https://localhost:44372/api/DeviceData with json body {
    "Latitude": 23,
    "Longitude": 43,
    "Altitude": 123,
    "Speed": 11,
    "DeviceId": 7
} I'm getting error: "Device doesn't exist!" thrown when device = null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are checking if device if exist you are using a wrong Id, you have to use DeviceId instead

```
 var exist = deviceContext.Devices.Any(i=> i.Id==deviceData.DeviceId);

 if (!exist) return BadRequest(Messages.DeviceNotExist);
```

and IMHO, replace

```
 deviceContext.DeviceData.Add(new DeviceData
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
            Latitude = deviceData.Latitude,
            Longitude = deviceData.Longitude,
            Altitude = deviceData.Altitude,
            Speed = deviceData.Speed,
            DeviceId = deviceData.DeviceId
        });
```

with

```
 deviceData.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
 deviceContext.DeviceData.Add(deviceData);
```